# Monogdb and Rails: get hash object with filtered attributes (I use mongoid)

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I what to get document from mongodb ()and send it to the client as json object but without certain fields in mongoid document (for example without _id or other attributes).

What is the best way to accomplish the task?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can decide what fields to select or deselect from the object while querying mongodb.
You can mention them as a parameter while querying.

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Retrieving+a+Subset+of+Fields#RetrievingaSubsetofFields-FieldNegation

example:

```
db.myCollection.find( { age : 20 }, { _id : 0 } );  // omit the _id field in result
```